# AEM: Convert/Adapt resource to page

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

Resource object needs to be adapted to Page class or a way to extract/refer page related to resource. I have tried following way; however it does not seems to work

```
final Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(pagePath);
final Page cPage = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
```

It returns `null` o cPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with PageManager

With path:
https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html#getPage-java.lang.String-

With resource:
https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html#getContainingPage-org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource-

Comment: The difference between these two methods is not just in the type of the parameter, but in the semantics.  This answer could be improved by elaborating on this difference and providing simple examples.

Comment: Everything is explained in java doc.

Comment: It is, but as soon as Adobe choose to move that domain and forget to set up redirects, this answer will become a lot less useful.